# jQuery - compatibility issue with Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, cross-browser, compatibility

At the moment, I am learning how to write in javascript and jquery. However, I wrote a simple jquery code where if you resize the window the page is automatically refreshed. It is working on Chrome, IE, Edge, Opera but not in Mozilla Firefox. Can someone check the code and tell me what is wrong and why it doesn't work with Firefox. I would be really grateful and thank you in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function(){location.reload(true);});
});
```

Best Regards,

George S.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try calling the function outside of `$(document).ready`

If that doesn't work try  `window.location.href=window.location.href;`  instead of  `location.reload(true);`

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    // nothing in here
});

$(window).resize(yourfunction);

 function yourfunction(){
      location.reload(true);
 }
```

or

```
$(window).resize( function () {
    location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: It worked with the following structure:

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $(window).resize(function(){
  window.location.href=window.location.href;
 });
}); `

After 6 minutes I will give you the best answer choice. Thank you for your fast reply, I am really grateful.

Comment: @GeorgeStoqnov No Problem. Glad I could help!